# Bourne Shell Programming: handling argument errors

Tags: shell, input

I am writing a shell program that takes in three arguments:

- an integer to determine the function of the program
- a file used by the program

The command is of the form myProgram num file. However, I want the program to output an error if the command only has 0, 1, or more than 2 arguments. That is, if I type "myProgram", "myProgram num", or "myProgram num file anotherWord", an error will be printed to the screen. Does anyone know how I could implement this into my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in variable `$#` contains the number of arguments that were passed to the script. You use this to check if there are enough arguments like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: myProgram num file" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# The rest of your script.
```

Comment: Error must be on **STDERR**, see my post.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, when using integers, the `(( ))` [is more intuitive](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) :

```
#!/bin/bash

if (($# < 2)); then
    printf >&2 "There's less than 2 arguments\n"
    exit 1
fi

if (($# > 2)); then
    printf >&2 "There's more than 2 arguments\n"
    exit 1
fi

if ! (($1)); then
    printf >&2 "First argument must be a positive integer\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f "$2" ]]; then
    printf >&2 "Second argument must be an exited file\n"
    exit 1
fi

# -->the rest of the script here<--
```

Moreover, to respect the *best practice* & proper coding, when printing an error, it must be so `STDERR` like I do with `printf >&2`

Answer (score 0):

Use shell built in $# to determine the number of arguments passed into your script. Your program name is not counted.

Comment: `$?` is the exit status of the last command run. `$#` is the number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for noting, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bash, then you can approach it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ $# -gt 3 ]
then
  echo "You did not provide the correct parameters"
  echo "Usage: blah blah blah"
fi
```

This is a very simple check.  You can also check man pages for getopt processing which is much more powerful when evaluating command line parameters.

be well

Comment: This will only display the message if there is less than 3 arguments, what if there is more than 3?

Comment: edited to show conditional if statement in bash.  to create a "and" use && instead of ||

Comment: You can rewrite that with an OR condition inside the test as `if [ $# -lt 3 -o $# -gt -4 ]`. Or you can just use `if [ $# -ne 3 ]` which does the same thing. Also, the original poster only wants 2 arguments, not 3.